# animate element without using jquery animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I need to move a element from one offset position to another with animation.
for which i was using

```
function getOffset(el) {
    el = el[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        left: el.left + window.scrollX,
        top: el.top + window.scrollY
    }
}
var _anchorElemPos = getOffset($element)
_animationElement.animate(_targetAnimPos); /*_targetAnimPos is the position where the element has to move.*/
```

It is working absolutely fine.But now I want the animation without `jquery animate()` function .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tried in CSS3 transitions? Anysample fiddle will help in understanding more :)

Comment: I try to understand, 
The css is not available to get parameters like window.scrollX or Y, but it can animate by parameters you write inside the css as hard coded. is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS3 animations. for moving you can use keyframes in CSS3

Comment: Even i dont want to use keyframes,
Is there any other solution?

Comment: in that case CSS3 transitions may be suitable

Comment: @Shikhathakur - sure - [here's a demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#Multiple_animated_properties_example) and there's more beneath it with links to jsfiddles and codepens you can play with

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.

HTML

```
<div id="movingObj"></div>
```

CSS3

```
#movingObj{
  background-color:red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-animation: moving 3s forwards;
  animation: moving 3s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moving {
  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 400px;}
}

@keyframe moving{
  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 400px;}
}
```